# How to access an element in 2d array in Smalltalk

Tags: arrays, matrix, smalltalk

I started coding in Smalltalk and got stuck here. I have this 2d array:

```
testArr := Array new: 1.
testArr at: 1
    put: ((Array new: 3)
            at: 1 put: '1A';
            at: 2 put: '1B';
            at: 3 put: '1C';
            yourself).
```

But if I want to access lets say first element of first array, what should I write to make it happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was in brackets.

```
^(testArr at: 1) at:1
```

returns

```
1A
```

as I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm tempted to take advantage of your question & answer, and elaborate a little bit on knowledge that belongs in the Smalltalk folklore (which you may already be aware of).

As we progresses in the use of Smalltalk, we will likely note that the `Array` class starts to play a decreasing role in our models. Why is that? Because it takes time to find out which are the objects our models will produce; the balance between too many and too few is a delicate matter, mostly clueless at the beginning.

Arrays and their composition are handy data structures. However, they solve the problem of organizing data at the expense of dealing with it. If the client of such a structure needs to know how data is stored as a prerequisite to act on it, then the message paradigm becomes semantically idle.

Let's imagine a matrix object. There are several ways to keep their entries: a one-dimensional array, an array of rows, an array of columns, a dictionary of (sparse) non-null entries, a triangular structure if the matrices are known to be symmetric/anti-symmetric/Hermitian, and a lot more for special cases. Of course, this variety makes no sense for the problem at hand and, in any case, it would be a bad idea to spend time considering the most general approach: **In Smalltalk, generality is attained at the message, not at the storage.**

Regardless of the internal organization of data, our objects should always offer protocols that are independent of the underlying structure. Back to the matrix example, even if our initial organization is an array of rows, the matrix object should work the same whether rows are arrays or more sophisticated *vector* objects that are also used for other ends. This means that when coding the internal access to entry `(i,j)` we should pretend we don't know the class of row `i` but only the message to access its `j`th element. Something on the lines of

```
    atRow: i column: j
      | row |
      row := self row: i.
      ^row at: j
```

Here we are not assuming that `row` is an `Array`; we are only assuming that it understands the `at:` message, which is the least we can assume when talking to a row object, whatever its actual nature. Of course, this code is only good under the assumption that rows are not recreated on the fly, as they would, had our class kept instead collections of columns. But this is ok, otherwise we would only need to add another class and override this and some few other *low level* messages.

In any case, the idea is to defer as much as possible any explicit knowledge about the internal organization so that it gets confined to a few private messages. One way to test we are applying this good practice is to make sure no low level code repeats in two or more methods. For instance, the use of the `row:` message above moves low level code away from `atRow:column:`, deferring it to another that makes sense for the (ideal) matrix protocol.

This example illustrates an important point: be suspicious of any code that needs to compose two `at:` messages. And --why not-- enjoy the beauty of not having to declare types.